# View the result set of a temporary table's data using SELECT within the stored procedure that creates the same temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have to create a stored procedure that adds a new pay period(adds 7 days) to a temporary table named `#TempPayPeriod`. This tables has all of the pay period data from the `PayPeriod` table. So I create a procedure that takes this permanent data move all of it into this temporary table and add a new pay period to that temporary table.

Which I did now I need to view that temporary table so I can compare it with this data and make sure it matches up

[image]

In my code I write `SELECT * FROM #TempPayPeriod` right after I execute the procedure. I get a `Command run successfully` but no result set to look at?

```
USE PR
GO

CREATE PROC spAddPay
            @StartDate smalldatetime = NULL,
            @EndDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempPayPeriod;

SELECT * INTO #TempPayPeriod FROM PayPeriod;

SET @StartDate = (SELECT MAX(PerFrom) FROM #TempPayPeriod);
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @StartDate);
SET @EndDate = (SELECT MAX(PerThru) FROM #TempPayPeriod);
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @EndDate);

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT #TempPayPeriod
    VALUES (@StartDate, @EndDate);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Record was not added';
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_NUMBER(),1) + ': ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_MESSAGE(),1);
END CATCH

EXEC spAddPay;
SELECT * FROM #TempPayPeriod;
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your temporary table loses scope once the stored procedure completes. You would need to move the select statement inside of the stored procedure or make the temporary table global by using the double pound sign notation. `##TempPayPeriod`

**OPTION 1 - Return the result from within the stored procedure**

```
USE PR
GO

CREATE PROC spAddPay
            @StartDate smalldatetime = NULL,
            @EndDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempPayPeriod;

    SELECT * INTO #TempPayPeriod FROM PayPeriod;

    SET @StartDate = (SELECT MAX(PerFrom) FROM #TempPayPeriod);
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @StartDate);
    SET @EndDate = (SELECT MAX(PerThru) FROM #TempPayPeriod);
    SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @EndDate);

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT #TempPayPeriod
        VALUES (@StartDate, @EndDate);
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT 'Record was not added';
        PRINT 'Error: ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_NUMBER(),1) + ': ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_MESSAGE(),1);
    END CATCH

    SELECT * FROM #TempPayPeriod
END

GO

EXEC spAddPay;

GO
```

**OPTION 2 - Use Global Temp Table**

```
USE PR
GO

CREATE PROC spAddPay
            @StartDate smalldatetime = NULL,
            @EndDate smalldatetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##TempPayPeriod;

SELECT * INTO ##TempPayPeriod FROM PayPeriod;

SET @StartDate = (SELECT MAX(PerFrom) FROM ##TempPayPeriod);
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @StartDate);
SET @EndDate = (SELECT MAX(PerThru) FROM ##TempPayPeriod);
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(day, 7, @EndDate);

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT ##TempPayPeriod
    VALUES (@StartDate, @EndDate);
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Record was not added';
    PRINT 'Error: ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_NUMBER(),1) + ': ' + CONVERT(varchar, ERROR_MESSAGE(),1);
END CATCH
END
EXEC spAddPay;
SELECT * FROM ##TempPayPeriod;
GO
```

Comment: So if I move it above `EXEC spAddPay` instead of below it, then it should work right?

Comment: it's not really a matter of moving it above `EXEC spAddPay`. more of a matter of adding it to the stored procedure. I'll edit my answer to clarify

Comment: because I just tried that and I'm still not getting a result set?

Comment: I see but where would the end of the procedure be I thought it ended after `GO`

Comment: With stored procedures it's best practice to mark the body with `BEGIN` and `END` tags. You've defined a reusable stored procedure above the code that calls it, but it seems like you are characterizing it all as a single script. THE `GO` keyword  is just a batch separator. There can be multiple `GO` commands in a single stored procedure, which is why I suggest using the `BEGIN` and `END` tags. I think you might be mixing concepts a little bit. Forgive me if you know this, but a script can be written and run without defining a stored procedure.

Comment: I see that, thanks man I wish they taught that in my text book